# What is the appropriate logic for the range filter to filter events that has a start date and end date?

Tags: tables, filter, range

I have a list of events that has a start and end date, and a range filter to filter the listing. My team and I have varying opinions on the logic of the range filter.

Consider the following filter range: 21 Aug - 21 Nov.

**Option 1:** Events that commence and conclude within the specified filter dates will be visible.
For example, an event scheduled from

- **25 Sep - 25 Oct**.

**Option 2:** Events will be displayed if any part of their date range falls within the filter range.
For instance, an event spanning from

- 21 July - **21 Sep**
- **25 Aug** - 25 Dec.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the site!

Unfortunately, I cannot decide between (1) and (2) based on the information your provided. Let me explain with two examples:

Use case A: Your "events" are like online conferences, consisting of multiple sessions, which I can attend separately (even if I have to register and pay all of it). In this case, I might want to see the sessions in the second half of the conference.

Use case B: Your "events" are vacation tours into the wilderness. I am available from start to finish, or I will not be able to participate at all. So I only want to see events which completely fall inside my filter range.

That's actually the basic issue with User Experience: There are no easy rules of thumb, and you need to look carefully at the use case every time. What are the user's goals (or pains)? What are the side conditions?

Very often in my company, I need to say that "consistency" (one UI pattern applied everywhere indiscriminately) is not the top design principle. It can be explained to all the developers very easily (because they think logically), but the more important design principle (in my view) is "appropriateness" (to the task). And this means you have to take a close look at the task, and for two (slightly) different tasks, the design recommendation might differ.